# How to bind a mouse click to open task-view in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, key-binding

I use the Sketchpad on Windows Ink Space a lot on my tablet and sometimes I wish to switch between applications *without* closing the Sketchpad and without moving much - ie: quickly swap to task view, click a different window for a second, swap to task view, re-open Sketchpad again.

I have a [Tonor Bluetooth mouse](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tonor-Portable-Bluetooth-Wireless-Optical/dp/B00WQQA7YA) which has [a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Y8z.png) that I don't use, but wish to rebind to toggle the task view window - this button is the DPI button.

How can I rebind this button on the bluetooth mouse to toggle the [task view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhkmb.png) window?

Perhaps an AutoHotKey script if Windows10 won't support it? But how, in AutoHotKey, can I get the name of this mouse button to run the command on press?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the Scan Code for the DPI-button (if it has one),
then you can remap it:

1) Run this script:

```
#NoEnv 
#SingleInstance Force
Process, Priority, ,High
#InstallKeybdHook
#InstallMouseHook
#UseHook

a:: Keyhistory
```

2. Press the DPI-button
3. Press a.

   If the DPI-button has been recognized, you can see the scan code (SC) of this key as first under SC. in Keyhistory

If the SC of this key is e.g. 144, then use this code

```
SC144:: Send, {Ctrl down}{Alt down}{TAB}{Alt up}{Ctrl up}
```

to bring up the AltTab menu.

See also
https://autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys

Comment: Ah, it seems it doesn't even get written because the the only SC record is key `a` :( So perhaps it just modified the mouse firmware and doesn't even go to the OS?